# How can I change Atom settings from the command line or a text editor?

Tags: command-line, atom-editor

I had an issue where when I opened Atom, it appeared with a blank screen, making it impossible to use - and impossible to change the settings from within Atom itself. I found another solution to the problem, but it made me wonder: Is it possible to change Atom's settings from outside Atom itself?

Is there a way to either:

- Change my Atom configuration from the command line? Or,
- Open a file I can edit to change Atom's configuration?

Either way, can you please direct me to documentation describing Atom's configuration command line tools or file so I can find how to properly change the setting I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Atom configuration is stored in either `config.json` or `config.cson`, which are stored in your `.atom` folder:

```
# Windows
$ cd %USERPROFILE%\.atom\

# Linux & macOS
$ cd ~/.atom/
```

There are cases in which launching Atom in safe mode (`atom --safe`) solves problem with frozen application windows.

See the [Atom Flight Manual](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#global-configuration-settings) for details on global configuration settings.